# Getting IDs of all google forms linked to spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have two google forms linked to google sheets. I am trying to get the IDs of both forms.

Doing:

```
FormApp.openByUrl(SpreadSheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet().getFormUrl())).getId()
```

only gives me one of the IDs.

Also how can I make my functions check if the ID is matches what I want?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

change the sheet name accordingly

```
const formID1 = FormApp.openByUrl(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1').getFormUrl()).getId();
    
const formID2 = FormApp.openByUrl(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 2').getFormUrl()).getId();
```